# Visual Studio webdeploy fail even when connection is validated?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I am trying to deploy my webapp VS2015 RC1 DNX 451. Even when I validate connection and run publish I get error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    
Error       Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED     
Error       More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("crocus.arvixe.com") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.       
Error       Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

[image]
Googling the issue and even trying to view host forum just says make sure username and password is correct. I am getting nowhere trying various settings. Any ideas how to debug the issue?

I am using Arvixe.com as host.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact [Arvixe.com](http://Arvixe.com).  They likely have some odd configuration on their servers but I would suspect they can help you resolve the issue.

Comment: I contacted them but the issue was not resolved they are consulting high level execs but i

Answer (score 0):

Arvixe does not support Web Deploy anymore.  Once they move you to their new servers Web Deploy won't be available to you.  In Visual Studio you can set up a Publish with FTP instead of Web Deploy.  If you're used to Web Deploy publishing your database changes, then you'll need to do those yourself with SQL scripts.  Entity Frameworks has an option to produce a SQL script for a migration, so you can use that to publish your EF database changes.